# Is there any package to mock/fake a small data set in order to get more number of rows in R/Python?

Tags: python, r, mocking, faker

I have a small data set(CSV) of 70 rows. I wanted to run some classification model. So I wanted to fake/mock the data points. so that the number of rows increase. I don't need the duplication of the rows. So is there any package in R/Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is unclear, please read and edit your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other users could help you. Also, add expected output.

Comment: you can use synthetic sampling to generate data points (SMOTE,ROSE)

Answer (score 0):

[fakir](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/fakir) generates fake data, some of which might be moldable into the form of your data set. As noted, a  [reproducible example, called a reprex](https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-whats-a-reproducible-example-reprex-and-how-do-i-do-one/5219) showing the structure of the data you want to extend is needed for specific suggestions, such as how to populate data frames of random data to rbind to your 70-row base.